# Submodule does not show in GitHub project

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I need a grey folder in one of my projects to show via github.

- I have tried `.submodule` update.
- I have tried `git submodule add "url blah blah blah"`
- I have tried changing the upstream of the grey folder.
- I have tried push origin master to all submodules and parent folders.

Of course I need 10 reputation points to post images.

*Rubyprojects holds "ruby" the folder I want to get into and make available.
*the parent folder of "Rubyprojects" contains a folder named ".gitmodules" that is blank.
*"Rubyprojects" also contains a folder called ".gitmodules" that is blank.

[image]

[Link to Grey-ed folder](https://github.com/stix11us/Rubyprojects)

Comment: It seems like the `git submodule add` command failed since the .gitmodules is empty. I usually just do `git submodule add -b master myremote` and then commit and push. Can you double check whether after the add your local .gitmodules is still empty?

Comment: Hi Tony! I added the "github" tag to your question and also added the image in question.

Comment: I tried the same command while inside the "rubyprojects" folder (parent folder of "ruby") resulting in "A git directory for 'Rubyprojects' is found locally with remote(s): origin git@github.com:stix11us/Rubyprojects.git if you want to reuse this local git directory instead of cloning again from git@github.com:stix11us/Rubyprojects.git use the '--force' option.  if the local git directory is not the correct repo or you are unsure what this means choose another name with the '--name' option.

Comment: I also tried "git submodule add -b master git@github.com:stix11us/Rubyprojects.git " resulting in "Rubyprojects already exists in the index.

Comment: ps: helmbert, thanks.  you rock!

Comment: when in "Rubyprojects" inputing "git submodule update --init" returns "No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'ruby'" Of course thanks for the help too qwattash :-)